# Form1 listbox not loading to form3 array when opened second time

Tags: arrays, vb.net, forms

Form3 contains array elements which loads its item from form1 listbox. 
When form3 is closed and again reopened then the array is becoming empty and there are no values in array that I can compare to.

Have tried to get another listbox in form3 and get elements through it by refreshing it everytime in every run. but it is not working.

```
form1

Do while xr.read()
If xr.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element AndAlso xr.Name = "Rating" Then
dim rating(0) as string = {xr.ReadElementString}
ListBox5.Items.Add(rating(0))

end If

 Private Sub RatingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RatingsEnteredVsAppxRatingsToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim myform As Form3
        myform = New Form3

        myform.Show(Form3)

        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub


form3

Public class form3

Dim toarray() As String = Form1.ListBox5.Items.OfType(Of String).ToArray()

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
'Compare operations to array
end sub

end class
```

I expect that when form3 is closed and opened from the menustrip of form1 again then the toarray should still contain the elements of listbox5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `InitializeComponent()` after showing Form3. It is recreating your control & removing the items that you have added to it when reading your xml.

```
Private Sub RatingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RatingsEnteredVsAppxRatingsToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim myform As Form3
    myform = New Form3

    myform.Show(Form3)
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and now the problem is not there. What I needed it working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead accessing the control "Form1.ListBox5" directly, you could provide an object/class that contains the values (rating array) and pass it to the Form1.ListBox5 and Form3 after instantiating.

Comment: Hello Thanks for joining for this questions answer.
you mean like

Dim toarray() As String = Form1.ListBox5.Items.OfType(Of String).ToArray()

I think I have already done what you are saying the problem appears when I close form3 and reopen it then the listbox5 becomes empty due to that the array also becomes empty.

Comment: Actually I think of something like this:
1. create object from class `RatingValues` in Form1 that reads and contains the values
2. consume values for ListBox5 from this `RatingValues` object
3. create property `RatingValues` in Form3
4. pass `RatingValues` form Form1 to `Form3.RatingValues`
5. use member `Form3.RatingValues` in Form3 for computation
6. eventually provide an OnChange event within class `RatingValues` in case the values changed and handle it in Form1 and Form3